# Calculating model evidence/marginals in Python

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian

My question pertains to bayesian inference and how to numerically calculate model evidence given some data and a prior and a posterior distribution.

Given conjugate priors, the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression#Model_evidence) specifies model evidence as the following:

[image]

Where sigma and beta are parameters, m is the model, Y is the data and X is the prior.

**Given the setup below, how do I calculate model evidence? I need something that returns one scalar number.**

Below I have a minimal working example of generating some data (draws from a normal) and assuming a prior (a normal) and a likelihood function (a gaussian). Notice how both the PDF of the data and the prior integrate to (approximately) one, while the likelihood function can take values over 1.

I am mainly confused as to how to "integrate out" the parameters from the model, and thus take model complexity into consideration. I can see how this can be done analytically if you can write down the log-likelihood function. But can't really see how this can result in one scalar number.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import scipy
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", palette="muted", color_codes=True)

%matplotlib inline

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)

data = np.random.normal(mu,variance,100)
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
density = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(data)
data_pdf = density(x)
prior_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
likelihood = np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sigma, 2.)))   

I1=scipy.integrate.trapz(data_pdf,x)
I2=scipy.integrate.trapz(prior_pdf,x)
I3=scipy.integrate.trapz(likelihood,x)

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,5))

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(3,1,1)
sns.despine(right=True)
ax1.plot(x,data_pdf,'k')
ax1.legend([r'$PDF(Data)$'],loc='upper left')

ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(3,1,2)
sns.despine(right=True)
ax2.plot(x,prior_pdf,'b')
ax2.legend([r'$Prior$'],loc='upper left')

ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(3,1,3)
sns.despine(right=True)
ax3.plot(x,likelihood,'r')
ax3.legend([r'$Likelihood$'],loc='upper left')

plt.tight_layout()

print(I1,I2,I3)
```

Comment: You might want to use the `conjugate_prior` package